# How to use lambdas together with functional interfaces and directly assign lambda to var in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, method-reference, functional-interface

I have this code:

```
package org.medianik.kotlindoc

fun main(){
    val creator:Creatable = toCreatable(::Created)// Ok. Compiles, and works fine
    val creator1:Creatable = ::Created // Compilation error
    val creator2:Creatable = ::Created as Creatable // ok enough to compile, but there is runtime exception
    val c = creator.create(5)
    val creator3:Creatable = toCreatable(c::doSmth1) // Ok. Compiles, works fine
    val creator4:Creatable = c::doSmth1 // Compilation error
    val creator5:Creatable = c::doSmth1 as Creatable // Again ok enough to compile, but there is runtime exception
    val creator6:Creatable = Creatable { i -> Created(i) } // Works fine, but that's not what I want
}

fun toCreatable(c:Creatable) = c

fun interface Creatable{
    fun create(i: Int) : Created
}
class Created(private var i: Int){
    fun doSmth1(add: Int): Created{
        return this.also { i+=add }
    }
}
```

Exception for creator2:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.medianik.kotlindoc.MainKt$main$creator2$1 cannot be cast to class org.medianik.kotlindoc.Creatable (org.medianik.kotlindoc.MainKt$main$creator2$1 and org.medianik.kotlindoc.Creatable are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Exception for creator5:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.medianik.kotlindoc.MainKt$main$creator5$1 cannot be cast to class org.medianik.kotlindoc.Creatable (org.medianik.kotlindoc.MainKt$main$creator5$1 and org.medianik.kotlindoc.Creatable are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I have no idea how to make creator1/4 work with method reference. Is there any ways to make them work? Because it seems senseless to me: if you pass method reference to a function as an argument -- it converts to interface, otherwise not. How does it work?

Are there some special casts for functions to interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into IntelliJ and also got errors in the lines

```
 val creator:Creatable = toCreatable(::Created)
 val creator3:Creatable = toCreatable(c::doSmth1)
```

The issue is, that `Creatable` is a named Interface that has the same Method signature like the class `Created` but this class does not implement the interface.

Note, a function does not implement an interface, even if they have a signature.

You could decare instead of an interface a function type. Note, this is not the same, but they can be handled almost the same.

```
typealias Creatable = (Int) -> Created
```

or you could write write a wrapper acceping such function type:

```
fun toCreatable(c:(Int) -> Created) = object: Creatable {
    override fun create(i: Int): Created {
        return c(i)
    }
}
```

this function accepts an function and returns an object that actually implements the interface.

Comment: Yes, I know about typealias. As said at kotlinlang.org: Functional interfaces vs. type aliases
Functional interfaces and type aliases serve different purposes. Type aliases are just names for existing types – they don't create a new type, while functional interfaces do.

Type aliases can have only one member, while functional interfaces can have multiple non-abstract members and one abstract member. Functional interfaces can also implement and extend other interfaces.

Considering the above, functional interfaces are more flexible and provide more capabilities than type aliases.

Comment: So I wanted to know if there is short way to use interface in lambda context(as if it were typealias).